# how can I refresh data in a collection view in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

I have a function to refresh the data of an array every 2 seconds

```
var timer = Timer()

func timeRefresh(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.refreshData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

I receive the data from a post service

```
@objc func refreshData(){

    post(postString, Route) { (res) in

        let success = res["success"]

        if success == true {
            let walkers = res["walkers"]

            for secondItem in walkers.array! {
                let duration = secondItem["duration"]

                self.timeCar.append(duration.stringValue) //this is the info that i need for the collection view

                }
            }

            print("array time \(self.timeCar)")

        }else{
            self.timeCar = ["-.-","-.-","-.-","-.-","-.-"]
        }
    }
}
```

I need refresh the collection view every second

```
cell.typeLabel.text = timeCar[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: reload in func timeRefresh() as per jake answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UICollectionView` has multiple ways of reloading data.

If you want every cell to be reloaded: 
`collectionView.reloadData()`.

If you want a specific section to be reloaded:  `collectionView.reloadSections(<Array of Sections>)`.

If you want to reload specific cells: `collectionView.reloadItems(<Array of IndexPaths>)`.

Comment: in my collectionview i have a image and two labels and i want to refresh only one label, that is posible?

Comment: @ErickArciniega when you update your data object and reload the collection view , collection view will automatically update the view .   collectionView.reloadData() should help after updating data object